# Laravel ORM created_at Field

Tags: php, laravel, orm, eloquent

i have two Models

1. Station
2. Price

I have set up the relations

```
class Station extends Model
{
    protected $keyType = "string";
    public $incrementing = false;

    public function prices()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Price');
    }

    public function latestPrice()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Price')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
    }
}


class Price extends Model
{
    protected $visible = ['created_at'];
    public function station()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Station');
    }
}
```

I fetch the Price, which belongs to a Station with

```
$stations = Station::all();
    $now = new Carbon();

    foreach ($stations as $station) {
        $lastPrice = $station->latestPrice;
        $t = $lastPrice->created_at;
        $difference = $now->diffInMinutes($test);
        if ($difference > 4) {
            //$this->saveNewPrice($station->id);
        }
    }
```

but i get the Error "Trying to get property of non-object". I don't know why this is the case.
If I dd 
    $lastPrice->created_at
i get the correct results, but if i try to use them i get the error.

Could anyone help me to solve this error?

Thank you so much,
c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be chances that for some `station` there is no `price` so it's better to wrap that part in `if` clause as:

```
foreach ($stations as $station) {
    $lastPrice = $station->latestPrice;
    if(lastPrice) {
        $t = $lastPrice->created_at;
        $difference = $now->diffInMinutes($test);
        if ($difference > 4) {
            //$this->saveNewPrice($station->id);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i also understand the error now.. I created a test case only for ONE Station.. the second station in the foreach loop triggers the error.. thank you!